# php header location http -> https redirect does not works

Tags: php, redirect, https

ich have a file test.php with this code:

```
<?php 
header('Location: https://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php');
?>
```

I call http://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php in the browser.

The redirection works, but I end on

http://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php

The script redirect me from http to http and not from http to https.

Our server is behind a load balancer. Because of this via script I need to ask $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL_CIPHER'] if I am an https or not. The server always thinks he is running on port 80.

Wenn I call https://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php manually in the browser, it works fine.

What could be the problem that the php redirect does not works? Could it be a server configuration?

Comment: probably another redirect. get the raw response, so you see the redirection.

Comment: hi,

the result is:

    HTTP/1.1 302 Found    
    Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 12:00:03 GMT   
    Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)   
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.23 ZendServer/6.3.0   
    Location: http://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php   
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8   

So why is there "Location: http://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php" and not "Location: https://www.mx-test-domain.de/test2.php". I am sorry but stackoverflow does not allow line break :(